# angular.module(...).provider(...).info is not a function

Tags: angularjs, node.js

My mean.js app is running in my local system but when upload on server it throws error like

```
angular.module(...).provider(...).info is not a function at angular-sanitize.js:714
at angular-sanitize.js:913
```

anyone help me solved this

Comment: What are the versions you are using for angular?

Comment: angular version 1.5.0

Comment: your code please

Comment: which code i need to share

Comment: sorry angular version-1.5.11 and angular-sanitize version-1.6.1

Comment: I have change angular version to 1.7.2 and sanitize to 1.7.2 but no use same errors please anybody help me

Answer (score 3):

It should work fine for your previous versions, see the below snippet:

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp", ['ngSanitize']);
app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
    $scope.myText = "<a href='http://google.com'>Google</a>";
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.11/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.1/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

    <p ng-bind-html="myText"></p>

</div>
```

However I was able to recreate your issue with different versions like below check the console:

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp", ['ngSanitize']);
app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
    $scope.myText = "<a href='http://google.com'>Google</a>";
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.11/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.3/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

    <p ng-bind-html="myText"></p>

</div>
```

One should **always** use same versions for all of your angularjs libraries. In some cases you might not get errors even when you use different versions, that is because you were not using breaking changes between those versions.

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp", ['ngSanitize']);
app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
    $scope.myText = "<a href='http://google.com'>Google</a>";
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.7.2/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.7.2/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

    <p ng-bind-html="myText"></p>

</div>
```

see the above versions of angular `1.7.2` it works fine, maybe you will have to clear your cache and try again.